# How to handle the [ist] tag after the IATA code IST is transferred to Istanbul Airport?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The IATA code *IST* and the [ist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ist) tag are currently used for [Istanbul Ataturk Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul_Atat%C3%BCrk_Airport). This airport will be closed on 31 December 2018 and its IATA code will be transferred to [Istanbul Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul_Airport), which is temporarily using the IATA code *ISL*.

If we use the [ist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ist) tag for the new airport as well, we won't be able to distinguish these two airports. I wonder if we have any solution for that.

Edit: The transfer has been [postponed](http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/gundem/istanbul-havalimanina-buyuk-tasinma-ertelendi-41056298) to March 2019.
Edit 2: The transfer took place on 6 April 2019.

Comment: I wonder how many questions would change as a result? I mean if people are just trying to get to fly to IST, then......probably not a big deal. But say, driving to the airport? Hmm. Different story.

Comment: @MarkMayo Not only driving, but all kinds of transportation, time required for connections, passport control queues, exchange offices, duty free shops... All may change.

Comment: @MarkMayo What do we need to do to finish this off? It's been about a week now and the questions about the new airport are already coming in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IST has finally moved, so it's about time to actually do something here.

My suggestion is to retag old questions as [ataturk-airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ataturk-airport) and use [ist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ist) for any new questions going forward.

Comment: Mark Mayo appears to be offline for a while. Maybe another moderator can help. @Willeke

Comment: All done. Please help me check that I did not burn anything in the process, and do not hesitate to re-tag, rename, edit, improve all posts which need to be updated.

Comment: @JoErNanO The [ist] tag seems OK, but [isl] is wrong. ISL was the temporary code for the new airport. I think the questions under [tag:isl] should be moved to [tag:ataturk-airport] and [isl] should be a synonym of [tag:ist].

Comment: @ahmedus Wikipedia says that [the new code for Ataturk Airport is ISL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul_Atat%C3%BCrk_Airport). That is where I got it from. Anyways, the isl <- ataturk-airport tag synonym exists.

Comment: @JoErNanO OK, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

We could mass-retag [ist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ist) to [former-ist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/former-ist) on the day it closes, so anyone searching for just "Istanbul" will at least see in the tags that it's possibly obsolete. (If someone wants to go through and fix current [ist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ist) questions that are not actually about the airport, that would be helpful.) Then continue to use [ist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ist) for the new airport, and add [isl](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isl) as a synonym to take care of the old questions.

Comment: Is mass retagging fixed? We had problems a couple years ago, but I never heard whether it was resolved or not.

Comment: I agree with the `isl` -> `ist` synonym for the new airport, but I'm not a fan of `former-ist`. Not that I have a better suggestion, though. :(

Comment: @choster Based on its usage on other SE sites, mass retagging works just fine.

Comment: @Machavity I'm not talking about other SE sites. Mass retagging was broken on TSE for a long time and it was never announced as fixed, so I'm asking for confirmation that it was.

Comment: Agreed in principle, though I would use a tag like `ataturk-airport` instead of `former-ist`.